# I have some dart files in a folder, how can I make a project by this folder?

Tags: dart

Like the title I have some dart files in a folder, I used them by command line: `dart run main.dart`, and now I want to import a library and use it.

What can I do?

I tried creating a file name `pubspec.yaml` and adding `dependencies`.

thank you.

Comment: If it's a command-line app, use "dart create" which defaults to a command-line app, and then move your files in there.  Anything in bin/ can be run with "dart run" and compiled to an exe with "dart compile".

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Are there any more ways to resolve this?

Comment: I can't answer that until you describe how the proposed answer doesn't meet your needs. :)